# How to create and image gallery using thumbnails and arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an image gallery with one large image and small thumbnails on its side that can be viewed by scrolling. I want to be able to change the picture in the middle in two ways: (1) using arrows located on top of the large image, (2) by clicking on the small thumbnails. I am stuck on step (1) having so far come up with the following code:

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>

<!--part a-->
<div id="imag">
<div class="imageDiv">
<div>
    <img src="http://www.talkandroid.com/wallpapers/images/1/small/1_3D_Landscape__54_.jpg" class="image"/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.ifpindia.org/ecrire/upload/mount_landscape01.jpg" class="image"/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_thum/gran_paradiso_wallpaper_landscape_nature_wallpaper_1538.jpg" class="image" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_thum/desert_wallpaper_landscape_nature_wallpaper_1062.jpg" class="image" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://www.bathnes.gov.uk/sites/default/files/siteimages/Environment/Trees-and-Woodlands/16cotswolds1-200x150.jpeg" class="image" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_thum/amazing_sunset_wallpaper_landscape_nature_wallpaper_1506.jpg" class="image" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="image" src="right arrow.png" class="rightarrow" width="10" height="35"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="image" src="left arrow.png" class="leftarrow" width="10" height="35"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--part a-->

<!--part b-->
<div id="box">
<div class="area">
    <img src="http://www.talkandroid.com/wallpapers/images/1/small/1_3D_Landscape__54_.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://www.ifpindia.org/ecrire/upload/mount_landscape01.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_thum/gran_paradiso_wallpaper_landscape_nature_wallpaper_1538.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_thum/desert_wallpaper_landscape_nature_wallpaper_1062.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://www.bathnes.gov.uk/sites/default/files/siteimages/Environment/Trees-and-Woodlands/16cotswolds1-200x150.jpeg"/>
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_thum/amazing_sunset_wallpaper_landscape_nature_wallpaper_1506.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
<!--part b-->

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#imag {
float:left;
padding:5px;
height:338px;
width:450px;
  }

.rightarrow {
position: absolute;
width:40px;
top: 10px;
left:400px;
}
.leftarrow {
position: absolute;
width:40px;
top: 10px;
left: 0px;
}

#box {
width: 222px;
height: 343px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
 }

.area img {padding-bottom: 5px;}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('img:not(:first)').hide();
$(".rightarrow").click(function () {
    $('img:not(:last):visible').
    hide().
    parent().
    next().
    children().
    show();
});
$(".leftarrow").click(function () {
    $('img:not(:first):visible').
    hide().
    parent().
    prev().
    children().
    show();
});
});
```

I have just started to learn HTML so I'm not too sure if this is the best way to do this but it's what I managed so far. Now the problem is that if I delete part b, part a works fine. If I delete part a and the js lines from the header section of the code then part b works fine. So my question is how can you combine both parts so that they work together correctly?

Comment: can you fiddle this in [jsffiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Yes i tried fiddle but I get the same result

Answer (score 0):

You can use html hashes to change which slide you are on. Then save the index with javascript and use that to go to the next or previous slide

```
<div class="carousel-full">
    <ul>
        <li id="item5">
            <img src="http://www.eightyonedesign.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/70-photography-2.jpg" />
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer elit elit, euismod ut fermentum sit amet, molestie non nisi. Cras placerat aliquet hendrerit. Nulla turpis sapien, ultricies ac rutrum ac, elementum vitae diam.</span>
        </li>
        <li id="item6">
            <img src="http://www.stevegoslingphotography.co.uk/images/general/steve_gosling_photography.jpg" />
            <span>Example long title goes here</span>
        </li>
        <li id="item7">
            <img src="http://www.eightyonedesign.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/70-photography-2.jpg" />
            <span>Example Title 1</span>
        </li>
        <li id="item8">
            <img src="http://www.stevegoslingphotography.co.uk/images/general/steve_gosling_photography.jpg" />
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer elit elit, euismod ut fermentum sit amet, molestie non nisi. Cras placerat aliquet hendrerit. Nulla turpis sapien, ultricies ac rutrum ac, elementum vitae diam.</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="carousel-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#prev">Previous</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item5">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item6">Item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item7">Item 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#item8">Item 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#next">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.carousel-nav {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.carousel-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.carousel-full {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.carousel-full ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.carousel-full li {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.carousel-full img {
    float: left;
}

.carousel-full span {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
```

And the javascript:

```
var current = 0,
    total = document.querySelectorAll('carousel-full li').length;

$('carousel-nav a').click(function () {
    var id = parseInt($(this).attr('href').slice(4));
    if (id) {
        current = id;
    }
});

$('carousel-nav a[href="#next"]').click(function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (current < total) {
        current = current + 1;
    } else {
        current = 0;
    }
    window.location.hash = 'item' + current;
});

$('carousel-nav a[href="#prev"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (current > 0) {
        current = current - 1;
    } else {
        current = total;
    }
    window.location.hash = 'item' + current;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not sure if your design is what I am looking for. I want to create something like this but with the thumbnails placed vertically not horizontally: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/